# Load Impact Service Not working

Tags: ibm-cloud

The load impact service is throwing an error when I try to click on the service instance link after provisioning.

Here is the Error..

No message body writer has been found for class java.util.Collections$SingletonList, ContentType: text/html

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix is experiencing some problems with this service and the support team is actively working to resolve it.

I will updated this post once a solution is provided.